# request.getRequestDispatcher("URL").forward(request,response) Not Working

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am trying to redirect to a jsp when an input validation error is found in case of data tampering. When I change the value for one of the fields it works properly but when value is changed for variable metricId[i] to "" it executes the code for request.getRequestDispatcher line but doesn't redirect it to the required page. Please help.

The code is as given below:

```
    public void validateGenerateCustomReportCommand(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        CustomReportCommand customReportCommand) {
    try {
        boolean invalidInputFound = false;
        System.out.println("Inside validateGenerateCustomReportCommand");
        String[] metricIds = customReportCommand.getMetricIds();

        String[] attrIdValueId = customReportCommand.getAttrValueIds();

        for (int i = 0; i < attrIdValueId.length; i++) {
            if (!(regexMatcher.validateSearch(attrIdValueId[i]))) {
                invalidInputFound = true;
                logger.error("Invalid input for Attribute Set");
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < metricIds.length; i++) {

            if(metricIds[i] == null){
                invalidInputFound = true;
            }

            if(metricIds[i] == ""){
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/moncoeError.jsp").forward(
                        request, response);
            }

            if (!(regexMatcher.validateMetricId(metricIds[i]))) {
                invalidInputFound = true;
            }

        }

        if (customReportCommand.getUnitValue() != null
                && customReportCommand.getUnitValue() != "") {
            Long unitValue = Long.parseLong(customReportCommand
                    .getUnitValue());
            if (unitValue < 1 || unitValue > 365) {
                invalidInputFound = true;
            }
        } 

        if (customReportCommand.getFromDate() != null
                && customReportCommand.getToDate() != null
                && customReportCommand.getFromDate() != ""
                && customReportCommand.getToDate() != "") {

            if (!(regexMatcher.validateDate(customReportCommand
                    .getFromDate()) || (!(regexMatcher
                    .validateDate(customReportCommand.getToDate()))))) {
                invalidInputFound = true;
            }

        }

        if(customReportCommand.getUnit() != "Days"){
            invalidInputFound = true;
        }

        if(customReportCommand.getName()==null || customReportCommand.getName() == ""){
            invalidInputFound = true;
        }else if(customReportCommand.getName().length() > 250){
            invalidInputFound = true;

        }

        if(customReportCommand.getDescription()==null || customReportCommand.getDescription() == ""){
            invalidInputFound = true;
        }else if(customReportCommand.getDescription().length() > 500){
            invalidInputFound = true;

        }





        if (invalidInputFound) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input found");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/moncoeError.jsp").forward(
                    request, response);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: what exception are you getting

Comment: Instead of == "", use .equals("") method.

Comment: No exception is received but validation is cleared which is not as per the business logic. I would be trying by using the .equals method but I need to check not equals and issue is in unit value not in unit field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your condition

```
    if(customReportCommand.getUnit() != "Days"){
        invalidInputFound = true;
    }
```

to

```
    if(customReportCommand.getUnit().equals("Days")){
        invalidInputFound = true;
    }
```